# Postfix regexp map for mailboxes

Tags: email, postfix, email-server, regex

I need to forward all email that comes to mailbox by some mask to one specific  mailbox.
For example if recipient mail is 79001234567 it should be forwarded.

line from /etc/postfix/main.cf

```
virtual_alias_maps = $alias_maps, $virtual_maps, ldap:/etc/postfix/imap-aliases.cf, ldap:/etc/postfix/imap-groups.cf, regexp:/etc/postfix/dummyregexp
```

Here is regexp I use:
/etc/postfix/dummymail

```
/^7\d{10}@domain.tld/   dummymail@domain.tld
```

part of /var/log/maillog

```
Mar 17 01:39:23 mail postfix/smtpd[24228]: connect from mail-qa0-f52.google.com[209.85.216.52]
Mar 17 01:39:23 mail postfix/smtpd[24228]: setting up TLS connection from mail-qa0-f52.google.com[209.85.216.52]
Mar 17 01:39:24 mail postfix/smtpd[24228]: Anonymous TLS connection established from mail-qa0-f52.google.com[209.85.216.52]: TL
Sv1 with cipher RC4-SHA (128/128 bits)
Mar 17 01:39:24 mail postfix/smtpd[24228]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from mail-qa0-f52.google.com[209.85.216.52]: 550 5.1.1 <79529002580@domain.tld>: Recipient address rejected: User unknown in local recipient table; from=<MY-EMAIL@gmail.com> to=<79529002580@domain.tld> proto=ESMTP helo=<mail-qa0-f52.google.com>
Mar 17 01:39:25 mail postfix/smtpd[24228]: disconnect from mail-qa0-f52.google.com[209.85.216.52]
Mar 17 01:39:57 mail imaps[23602]: accepted connection
```

Also, I've tryed to add other lines to /etc/postfix/dummymail, and this one worked for me

```
/dddummymail@domain.tld/    dummymail@domain.tld
```

So I consider something wrong with my regexp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace `\d` with a POSIX character class:

```
/^7[[:digit:]]{10}@domain.tld/ dummymail@domain.tld
```

Comment: Oh my, it was that simple! Thank you hundred times, Gryphius!!!